# How do I read these moq setup expressions?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Alternate title: What do these expressions mean?

EDIT: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767446/moq-confusion-setup-v-setup) almost helped, but just explained the difference between the two setup functions, not how to read them.

I'm learning how to use moq and putting together a basics training for my team, and after going through [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZ2Psa_Bn2Q) and looking up [other stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286783/how-do-i-raise-an-event-when-a-method-is-called-using-moq) (among others), I think I understand it well enough to use it, but only in the sense of "this is just the way it's done". I have no justification or ability to explain the syntax. Please help.

For the record, I understand the use of C# templating and expressions and functions and actions and events alone, but jamming them together? The meta is real.

Consider the following code snippet from the one of the video demonstration's unit tests, `Should_Mock_Events_Based_On_Action()` ([unit test source](https://github.com/skimedic/presentations/blob/master/UnitTesting/MOQExamples/B_Advanced/B_MockingEvents.cs), [IRepo source](https://github.com/skimedic/presentations/blob/master/UnitTesting/MOQExamples/SystemsUnderTest/IRepo.cs)):

```
var mockRepo = new Mock<IRepo>();
mockRepo.Setup(x => x.AddRecord(null))
    .Raises(m => m.FailedDatabaseRequest += null, this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

1. The `Setup(...)` function seems to read, "Set up a function that takes an `IRepo` and then calls `AddRecord(...)` with `null`." But this setup is mocking up `IRepo.AddRecord(...)`, which is not an expression. Somehow this gets translated inside mock to "Set up a function *for* `IRepo` called `AddRecord(...)` such that, when it takes `null`, it behaves a certain way." But it doesn't read that way. **How is this supposed to read?** Somehow the expression gets turned into an actual function call somewhere, somehow.
2. The `Raises(...)` function really confuses me. It looks like it is saying, "The previously set up function raises an event that takes an `IRepo` and adds `null` to its event handler." And...somehow this makes the event happen?  That `+= null` operation doesn't return anything, and I haven't been able to figure out how this gets understood as the event that this handler is looking for. I've found a number of articles and SO posts that show that this is just how it's done, but none of them (that I've found yet) explain *why*. **How is this supposed to read?**

Comment: When AddRecord `IRepo.AddRecord` method is called with `null` parameter, then it raise event `FailedDatabaseRequest` with empty event args `EventArgs.Empty`.

Comment: I see that it does, but I see little correlation between the syntax and what it does

Comment: I think that perhaps you should spend some time learning about anonymous functions and LINQ. Coming to Moq knowing about those, I find the syntax to be refreshingly obvious and clear - but from your question and comments it doesn't appear that you understand how passing a function as a parameter works. Until you understand that then there's very little I can do to help - knowing how to pass functions as parameters is fundamental to using Moq.

Comment: @MattJones : I _think_ I understand how those work, but I don't know how it is called. In no part of the unit testing do _I_ call the anonymous function, but it evidently gets called _somewhere_. Suppose I pass an expression into a function. Now what? It does nothing until it is called. So how does moq call it and when?

Comment: The anonymous function is effectively stored within the mock alongside the corresponding action to take. Then, when you make a call on the mock that matches the anonymous function the mock takes the action you set up.

Comment: If you look in the web page you linked to, you can see `controller.SaveCustomer(null);` - this (I assume) is calling the `IRepo.AddRecord` method with `null` as a parameter, which is what was set up earlier.

Comment: I dug into it a bit more and found that my confusion was rooted in not understanding C#'s `Expression<>`. It wasn't anonymous functions or LINQ or lambdas that were my problem, but rather not knowing that C# could deconstruct expressions into a expression tree of their base pieces and then construct equivalent functionality out of something else, all at runtime. Cool. Thanks for your comments anyway though.

Comment: Glad you finally got to the bottom of it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering own question.

My confusion was rooted in not understanding how C#'s expressions worked (not lambda expressions, but specifically `Expression<>`). They are an exposure of compiler theory (specifically "expression trees") and can be used to deconstruct lambdas into pieces, including parameters, constants, binary operators, and others. Moq takes advantage of this and uses the pieces to construct its own object with the specified functionality + support code for verification. I didn't know C# could do this.

[MSDN Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Tutorial series that alleviated my confusion: [C# Expression Trees](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P60pt5xlms0&list=PLRwVmtr-pp06SlwcsqhreZ2byuozdnPlg)

Answer (score 2):

Say I have an interface `ITest` that has a single method:

```
public interface ITest
{
    bool IsEvent(int input);
}
```

I then want to mock this - and remember, right now I have **no** actual concrete class.

```
        var mock = new Mock<ITest>();
```

Now I want to set up 2 calls:

```
        mock.Setup(x => x.IsEven(1)).Returns(false);
        mock.Setup(x => x.IsEven(2)).Returns(true);
```

This is saying to the mock object:

> If your method IsEven gets called with a value of 1 then return false.
>   If your method IsEven gets called with a value of 2 then return true.

You are **setting up** behaviour on your mocked object.

So if I then do this in code:

```
        var for1 = mock.Object.IsEven(1);
        var for2 = mock.Object.IsEven(2);
```

Variable `for1` will be false and `for2` will be true because I told the mock object that was what it should do. The parameter for `Setup` effectively says "This is the behaviour I want you to look out for and I will then tell you what to do". In my case, I use the `Returns` method to specify what actually gets returned from my mock object in that specific case.

In your specific case:

```
        mockRepo.Setup(x => x.AddRecord(null))
            .Raises(m => m.FailedDatabaseRequest += null, this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

This is saying to the mocked object

> If someone calls the AddRecord method with a parameter of null then
>   raise an event of type FailedDatabaseRequest

For more information on the `Raises` method, have a look at the [Moq quickstart documentation for events](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#events) here.

For a more in depth view of raising events with Moq there is some useful information [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MoqEvents_2.aspx) - specifically it talks about the `+= null` that is causing you some confusion:

> To raise an event from a mock object we use its Raise method. This
>   accepts two parameters. The first is a lambda expression that includes
>   an empty event subscriber for the event to raise. Although not the
>   most elegant syntax, this is required to allow Moq to understand how
>   the event is used. The second parameter provides the event arguments
>   that will be included with the event.

Comment: The last link was somewhat helpful, but only seemed to go so far as to say that it wasn't elegant syntax. I dug into the moq github repo. All I know is that 

`mockRepo.Setup(x => x.AddRecord(null))` calls `public ISetup<T> Setup(Expression<Action<T>> expression)` in `WhenPhrase.cs`

and that is forwarded to `internal static MethodCall Setup(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Condition condition)` in `Mock.cs`

I tried to figure out how `var mockRepo = new Mock<IRepo>()` set up the mock object in `WhenPhrase.cs`. I eventually gave up. I still don't understand how this works.

Comment: Read about passing functions and actions in C# using anonymous functions - until you understand that, then this will be very opaque to you.